Facing an issue with Solana Smart Contract: error 0x65
I’m encountering an issue with my Solana smart contract that results in the error InstructionFallbackNotFound. This error suggests that the Anchor framework is unable to find a corresponding function to handle the instruction I'm trying to invoke. Specifically, it occurs when I attempt to initialize a key. This indicates that the instruction might not be properly recognized by the smart contract. To resolve this, I need to ensure that the instruction discriminator is calculated correctly and that my function signatures match the dispatched instructions. Additionally, I should double-check that the transaction structure and account requirements are correctly configured to avoid this error.

Error initializing key: [Error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x65. 
Logs: [
  "Program 2FCmh5tZDnu7V1wFjwj6JSuGs2nVkBViUKh8zkXYiRQF invoke [1]",
  "Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported.",
  "Program 2FCmh5tZDnu7V1wFjwj6JSuGs2nVkBViUKh8zkXYiRQF consumed 1835 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program 2FCmh5tZDnu7V1wFjwj6JSuGs2nVkBViUKh8zkXYiRQF failed: custom program error: 0x65"
]. 
Catch the SendTransactionError and call getLogs() on it for full details.]


Smart Contract (lib.rs)

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("2FCmh5tZDnu7V1wFjwj6JSuGs2nVkBViUKh8zkXYiRQF");

// Define the data structure to hold the key
#[account]
pub struct KeyData {
    pub key: String,
}

#[program]
pub mod key_storage {
    use super::*;

    // Initialize the key (validate length and store it in the account)
    pub fn initialize_key(ctx: Context<InitializeKey>, key: String) -> Result<()> {
        require!(key.len() == 5, CustomError::InvalidKeyLength);
        let key_data = &mut ctx.accounts.key_data;
        key_data.key = key.clone();
        msg!("Key initialized by: {}", ctx.accounts.signer.key());
        msg!("Key: {}", key);
        Ok(())
    }

    // Update the key
    pub fn update_key(ctx: Context<UpdateKey>, key: String) -> Result<()> {
        require!(key.len() == 5, CustomError::InvalidKeyLength);
        let key_data = &mut ctx.accounts.key_data;
        key_data.key = key.clone();
        msg!("Key updated by: {}", ctx.accounts.signer.key());
        msg!("New Key: {}", key);
        Ok(())
    }

    // Verify the public key
    pub fn verify_key(ctx: Context<VerifyKey>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Public key verified: {}", ctx.accounts.signer.key());
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeKey<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub key_data: Account<'info, KeyData>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateKey<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub key_data: Account<'info, KeyData>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct VerifyKey<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum CustomError {
    #[msg("The key must be exactly 5 characters.")]
    InvalidKeyLength,
}

Frontend Code (DID.js)
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as solanaWeb3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';

const PROGRAM_ID = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey('2FCmh5tZDnu7V1wFjwj6JSuGs2nVkBViUKh8zkXYiRQF');
const HARD_CODED_KEY = 'abcde';

const getInstructionDiscriminator = (instructionName) => {
    const hash = sha256(instructionName);
    return Buffer.from(hash.slice(0, 8), 'hex');
};

const DID = () => {
    const [publicKey, setPublicKey] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

    const initializeKey = async () => {
        try {
            const savedPin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('encryption_key');
            const decryptedWallet = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(savedPin, "252525").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

            if (!decryptedWallet) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'Decryption failed.');
                return;
            }

            const key = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(decryptedWallet).secretKey);
            const wallet = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(key);

            const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
            const instructionDiscriminator = getInstructionDiscriminator('initialize_key');
            const instructionData = Buffer.concat([instructionDiscriminator, Buffer.from(HARD_CODED_KEY)]);

            const instruction = new solanaWeb3.TransactionInstruction({
                keys: [{ pubkey: wallet.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }],
                programId: PROGRAM_ID,
                data: instructionData,
            });

            transaction.add(instruction);

            const signature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet]);
            setMessage(`Transaction successful! Signature: ${signature}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error initializing key:', error);
            if (error.message) {
                setMessage(`Error: ${error.message}`);
            } else {
                setMessage('Error initializing key. Check the logs.');
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
            <Text>Public Key: {publicKey}</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Enter 5-character key"
                value={HARD_CODED_KEY}
                editable={false}
                style={{ borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginVertical: 10, padding: 5 }}
            />
            <Button title="Initialize Key (Program 1)" onPress={initializeKey} />
            <Text>{message}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default DID;

